# Не запустился jii в XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, yii, composer, htdocs

Все пути верные, делаю пошагам. Но на одном из шагов никак не происходит запуск приложения. Что может быть? По фронту и бэкенду все аналогично, отображается не только папка web.

[image: Общий вид]

[image: Индекс отображается вместо стартовой страницы jii]

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vabessonova.test
    DocumentRoot "D:\PHP\XAMPP\1\htdocs\yii-application\frontend\web"
    
    <Directory "D:\PHP\XAMPP\1\htdocs\yii-application\frontend\web">
```

В любом случае спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Была проблема в том, что был удален index
[image: Удаленный index]

Был удален по причине, что XAMPP презентовал "DashBoard", пришлось вернуть и в нем прописать:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/yii-application/frontend/web');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

где yii-application/frontend/web - это путь к папке frontend -> web